# Range.Find works only once, then I must restart Excel

Tags: excel, vba, range, excel-2019

I have a very long and convoluted macro. One particular bit contains the following:

```
Set rng = Sheets(sht1).Range("A1:D50").Find("abc")
if not rng is nothing then
     some stuff
else
     error message
end if
```

This works just fine...once. If I want to run it again (say because I am bug testing another part of the macro), I have to shut down Excel completely (every open workbook). Between each. And. Every. Run.

If I do not, then the next time this line is run, it comes back as Nothing and I get my error message. Nothing in the actual Excel text is changed; there is exactly one cell that contains my search terms, and it has not been modified.

I have tried using rng.clear and rng.calculate and rng.clearcontents and set rng = sheets(1).range("A1") and none of those solve the problem.

How do I tell Excel to find the range a second time, or to forget it did it the first time? Or could there be something else causing this problem?

These files are huge and take time to load. It's annoying for the end user and VERY annoying for me as the one who has to stomp out bugs, which often requires lots of runs.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Have you tried any of the optional arguments as well? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: @brax - It finds exactly what it is supposed to the first time, and no text has changed, so it should find it again.

Comment: If you open a blank workbook, put "abc" somewhere in A1:D50, and try out the line `Debug.Print Range("A1:D50").Find("abc").Address`. You can run it a hundred times and it works a hundred times. The fact that it doesn't work for you means one of two things.  The other parameters of `Find` have changed due to other lines of code or the user's interference. Or the values in the worksheet have changed and "abc" is no longer found.

Comment: If you open the Find and Replace menu (Ctrl+F) and make changes to those settings, they are saved, and when you do `Range.Find` without specifying the settings, it applies those same settings from the Find and Replace menu. This means that if a user changes the "Look In" to "Comments", `Range.Find` will not work anymore because you're probably expecting it to be `xlValues`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer, though I still don't know why I had the problem. Thanks Toddleson for pointing me in the right direction.

That line was the only range.find in the entire code. But, when I used ctrl+f to look at the front end interface of find, I saw that the "Match entire cell contents" box was checked, which is why it was failing to find it, and why closing Excel entirely undid the problem.

So I changed the find line to the following, and it now works perfectly without having to close.

```
Set rng = Sheets(sht1).Range("A1:D50").Find("abc", , , xlPart)
```